# Trouble understanding what is a Projection Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, statistics

As I understand, a Projection Matrix is an idempotent matrix (i.e. $A^2 = A$) that can take any vector and project onto a new vector.

As an example:

Suppose we have a projection matrix P:

P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

And we have a vector v:

v = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}

The projection of v using P by multiplying them:

v' = Pv = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}

Thus, the vector v = (2,3) is projected onto the point (2,0) by the projection matrix P.

**My Problem:** In the field of Statistics and Probability, the standard linear regression model is also said to be related to the idea of projection matrices. For instance:

$$y = X\beta + \epsilon$$

where:

- $y$ is a vector of response values,
- $X$ is a matrix of explanatory variables
  -$\beta$ is a vector of unknown parameters that we want to estimate,
- $\epsilon$ is the error vector.

The OLS estimate of $\beta$, i.e. $\hat{\beta}$, is given by: $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X'y$

The  predicted values,  $\hat{y}$, are given by: $\hat{y} = X\hat{\beta}$

We can use this to define the projection matrix $P$:

$$\hat{y} = Py = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$

**My Question:** Let's assume a regression model is fitted to the above data. We then take a **single vector** of observed data points $X$, pass it through  (i.e. project it) the regression model (i.e. the Projection Matrix) and in the end, we get a single predicted value of $\hat{y}$ (i.e. a **single point**).

**Thus, it seems like the Projection Matrix is taking a vector and projecting it into a single point. To me, this does not seem correct. A Projection Matrix is supposed to project a vector onto a new vector. But in this case, the Projection Matrix is projecting a vector onto a point.**

Can someone please help me understand what am I not doing correctly?

- Have I not correctly understood the definition of a Projection Matrix?  (i.e. vector to single point projections are allowed?)
- Or is $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ not a Projection Matrix?
- Or is $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ actually a Projection Matrix and it is projecting a vector onto another vector (i.e. maybe $\hat{y}$ is actually a vector?)

Thanks!

Comment: The matrix projects $y$ onto $\hat y$, which is also a vector (of the same size). You can view real numbers as vectors as well, as a side note.